# Jquery: convert html to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Is there a easy way to get an array out of a string (html) with jquery/javascript like:

html:

```
<h1>this is a test</h1>
<p>This is a test</p>
<p>This is a test</p>
<h2>this is a test</h2>
<p>This is a test</p>
```

to an array:

```
array[0]['tag'] = 'h1'
array[0]['value'] = 'this is a test'
array[1]['tag'] = 'p'
array[1]['value'] = 'this is a test'
array[2]['tag'] = 'p'
array[2]['value'] = 'this is a test'
array[3]['tag'] = 'h2'
array[3]['value'] = 'this is a test'
array[4]['tag'] = 'p'
array[4]['value'] = 'this is a test'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*updated*

JS

```
var htmlstring = "<h1>this is a test</h1><p>This is a test</p><p>This is a test</p><h2>this is a test</h2><p>This is a test</p>",
    map = { };

$(htmlstring).each(function(_, node) {
    map[ _ ] = { };
    map[ _ ][ node.nodeName ] = node.textContent;
});

console.log(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KzfpK/

Comment: But the html is in a string. And not yet an existing element.

Comment: @Jaap: updated, you can just wrap a "valid" htmlstring into the jquery constructor aswell.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should do the trick but it will not work recursively (only for direct body  children).

```
var tags = [];

$('body').children().each( function( index, element ) {
    tags.push({ 
        'tag' : element.nodeName.toLowerCase(), 
        'value' : element.text()
    });
});
```

Comment: But the html is in a string. And not yet an existing element.

Comment: just pass the string into the `$()` selector then, e.g `$('<body><h1>text</h1></body>').children()`

Comment: @Jaap make it to an jquery object then: $(htmlString) and run both scibuff and @jAndy´s code.

Answer (score 0):

here an idea

```
$('body *').each(function(i){
console.log($(this).text());
console.log(this.nodeName);
console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: beware: using the `*` can be very slow